# Excel VBA - list all VBA environmental variables

Tags: vba, excel

How can I get excel to list me all available environmental variables on my "temp" sheet? Below code doesnt return anything for me...

```
Sub ListEnvironVariables()
    Dim strEnviron As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 255
        strEnviron = Environ(i)
        If LenB(strEnviron) = 0& Then Exit For
        Debug.Print strEnviron
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

few lines modified from your code as below.

```
Sub ListEnvironVariables()
    Dim strEnviron As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 255
        strEnviron = Environ(i)
        If LenB(strEnviron) = 0& Then Exit For
        With Worksheets("temp")
            .Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = strEnviron
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no output with this macro. I can see it running, but the temp sheet remains empty. I am on Windows 10 with Office 2013, the code should run on machines with earlier versions though...

Comment: Note: it seems that your loop from 1 to 255 has issues. I adjusted the code to this and its working: .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = strEnviro

Comment: I just tested this and it is working with: .Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = strEnviron

Answer (score 2):

Now I have changed the coding . This will list out all of the environment variables in your immediate window.  If you can't see this, choose this menu option:

```
  Sub ListEnvironmentVariables()
'each environment variable in turn
Dim EnvironmentVariable As String
'the number of each environment variable
Dim EnvironmentVariableIndex As Integer
Dim i As Long
'get first environment variables
EnvironmentVariableIndex = 1
EnvironmentVariable = Environ(EnvironmentVariableIndex)
'loop over all environment variables till there are no more
Do Until EnvironmentVariable = ""
'get next e.v. and print out its value
With Worksheets("temp")
            .Cells(i, 1).Value = EnvironmentVariableIndex
            .Cells(i, 2).Value = EnvironmentVariable

        End With
'go on to next one
EnvironmentVariableIndex = EnvironmentVariableIndex + 1
i = i + 1
EnvironmentVariable = Environ(EnvironmentVariableIndex)
Loop
End Sub
```

Plz look into this also for further reference
http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s387/environment-variable-vba.htm

Comment: this outputs into the VBA Immediate window, not the excel sheet itself. How can I get to paste into the "temp" worksheet instead?